# Ufw causing trouble with DHCP or WPA?

Tags: 10.04, networking, wireless, network-manager, firewall

It appears that enabling UFW is causing my network connection to drop periodically on a WPA-Enterprise network, according to the network-manager GUI app (and the lack of a server response to web browsing for a minute or so while it is out).  Is this because UFW is preventing something needed for WPA or DHCP when configured with the defaults?

Comment: I guess everything works fine when you disable UFW?

Comment: Which firewall rules have you set up?

Comment: Did the answer below answer your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running 10.04 on a Dell X300 (old) laptop with ufw enabled (through GUFW gui tool : sudo apt-get install gufw, then configure from system/administration/firewall configuration).

We use a non-hidden SSID configured with WPA2 and PEAP authentication.  No issues.

UFW is configured as default - deny all incoming, allow all outgoing.

As a result, DHCP should be unaffected since technically it's outbound traffic (a network broadcast to the local subnet), to which the DHCP server responds appropriately.

Like the commenters above, I presume that everything works if you disable UFW (sudo ufw disable)?  If so, further investigation required - perhaps a look at /var/log/messages or similar.